# Blazor WASM application ClaimsPrinicpal and roles claim

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to build a Blazor WASM application that can display different UI elements depending on the value(s) in the `roles` claim of the token received from Azure AD.

I have a simple debug view where I iterate all claims:

```cs
@foreach(var claim in @context.User.Claims)
{
    @claim
    <br/>
}
```

Here I can clearly see the user has the following claim:

> roles: ["Developer"]

This is received from the AAD app registration where I have assigned the role `Developer` to my own user.

I would expect any of these statements to then return true:

```cs
context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Developer") // false
context.User.IsInRole("Developer") // false
```

So I wrote a custom implementation and parse the claim myself:

```cs
@if(context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var rolesValue = context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "roles").First().Value; // The roles claim value is an array as a string
    // Deserialize the string into a list
    var roles = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(rolesValue);
    // Print out all roles
    Console.WriteLine("Roles:");
    
    foreach(var role in roles!)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(role); // Prints 'Developer'
    }
}
```

All of these snippets are run inside the following Blazor components:

```html
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
    </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

The entire application is set up using the following [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

How come I have to do this custom claim interpretation when I clearly have the claim for the user? Just [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=user.isinrole%20returns%20false) this issue returns so many results but I still haven't been able to solve it. The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#procedural-logic) uses the method in a slightly different way, but why can I enumerate the claim in my context but still not use any of the utility methods on the User?

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
Implemented the sample from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#procedural-logichttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#procedural-logic):

```cs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;
    if (user.IsInRole("Developer"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Developer role from OnInitialized");
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No role from OnInitialized"); // Always gets here, even after logging/in out or using private browsing
    }
}
```

The enumerated claims still list the developer role in the roles claim: `roles: ["Developer"]`.

Comment: I think you find the solution yourself in the documentation you  reported. The second link from Microsoft Docs. Did you try to implement that example?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated my sample above, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is a ton of ways to solve this depending on your auth scenario. For my scenario, I needed to know the role when authenticating in a SPA against Azure AD. The [following instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/azure-active-directory-groups-and-roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-user-account) solved that.

I only made one modification to those instructions, and that was to the `CustomAccountFactory`. I set the role claim that enabled me to use to built in `User.IsInRole`

```cs
public override async ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(
    CustomUserAccount account,
    RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
{
    var initialUser = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

    if (initialUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var userIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)initialUser.Identity;

        foreach (var role in account.Roles)
        {
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
    }

    return initialUser;
}
```

The problem with using `User.IsInRole` initially seems like I was receiving an array of roles as a string.
This could also work, but would be fragile:

```cs
User.IsInrole(@"[""Developer""]")
```